# Pyramid install under Python 3.3 gives pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: <myproject> under Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

I have freshly installed Python 3.3 (x64) and PyWin32, and then did the following (`mindeningyen-env` is the directory of the virtualenv, `mindeningyen` is the name of the app):

```
distribute_setup.py
easy_install virtualenv
virtualenv --no-site-packages mindeningyen-env
cd mindeningyen-env
Scripts\activate
easy_install pyramid
pcreate -s alchemy mindeningyen
cd mindeningyen
setup.py develop
pip install waitress
```

And then I get the following trace:

```
(mindeningyen-env) D:\prg\mindeningyen-env\mindeningyen>pserve development.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\Scripts\pserve-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.4', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 50, in main
    return command.run()
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 304, in run
    global_conf=vars)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 328, in loadapp
    return loadapp(app_spec, name=name, relative_to=relative_to, **kw)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 271, in loadobj
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 454, in get_context
    section)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 476, in _context_from_use
    object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 406, in get_context
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 620, in get_context
    object_type, name=name)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 640, in find_egg_entry_point
    pkg_resources.require(self.spec)
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.31-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 706, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "d:\prg\mindeningyen-env\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.31-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 604, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: mindeningyen
```

Any ideas why it doesn't find the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using virtualenv (either installed, or python builtin), one shouldn't say things like
`setup.py develop`, because that will use the python interpreter, which is found in registry. One should ensure the virtualenv is activated `Scripts\activate`, and after that every python run should use python, so, the correct form is:

```
python setup.py develop
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the new [Python 3.3 native virtual env](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) implementation, I can use Pyramid on Python 3.3 just fine:

```
python3.3 -m venv mindeningyen-env
cd mindeningyen-env/
source bin/activate 
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py 
bin/easy_install pyramid
bin/pcreate -s alchemy mindeningyen
cd mindeningyen
python setup.py develop
cd ..
bin/pserve mindeningyen/development.ini
```

Comment: Lucky you, but see the note here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html#installing-the-virtualenv-package Since I haven't used python's own virtualenv, I though it would be easier for me to follow the known route.

Comment: @pihentagy: The documentation predates the Python 3.3 venv setup. Did you try following my command history?

Comment: On it's way, will get you updated... However, the doc suggests to use virtualenv as a safe bet, and I seemded to find some gotcha. I suspect at some point I just typed `setup.py`, which uses the python from outside the virtual environment.

Comment: The Python 3.3 venv is more efficient but is basically the same thing.

Comment: Yes, your way works. Will double check not to fire .py files without writing python before, because windows runs the default installed python interpreter in that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, are you using cygwin to execute these commands? ::confused::